# How to check details of total denies of security rules in Google cloud?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, firebase-security, google-cloud-monitoring

How to check details of total denies of Firebase security rules in Google cloud? I have added the screenshot which is shown in the Firebase console. But it shows "
Use advanced analysis and alerting tools in Cloud Monitoring" But when I go to google cloud it does not have any details of that. I have also attached the screenshot of the Google cloud console which is opened when I click the cloud monitoring button in the Firebase console. [image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently nothing in the console that shows you why a request was denied by security rules.  Feel free to [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for that.

The best way to develop security rules (with Firestore) is to do that with the [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator), which will give you more details about why a request from your test code was denied.

Comment: Down side is troubleshooting, since denies are basically violations, so unexpected things are happening, but we don't have means to understand what are those

Comment: @doug I filed a feature request, when would this "feature" become available? I am actually surprised that this wouldnt be out of the box since, monitoring is vital to any system!?